# type/value mismatch at argument 3 in template parameter list

Tags: c++, priority-queue

I am almost successful in implementing huffmann code. I am encountering an error, the error goes like this:

```
>>prog.cpp: In function 'int main()':
>>prog.cpp:49:57: error: type/value mismatch at argument 3 in template parameter list for 'template<class _Tp, class _Sequence, class _Compare> class std::priority_queue'

>>priority_queue<Node*,vector<Node*>,comparitor<Node*>> pq;
                                                         ^
>>prog.cpp:49:57: note: expected a type, got 'comparitor' Node*>
```

I have tried pointers before, this is the first time I am getting such error.

Can anyone explain, why such error arise? Here is my commented code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include<queue>
class Node{
    public:
    int freq;
};
template<typename T>
bool comparitor(T a, T b)
{
    if(a->freq>b->freq)
    {return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    } // this is for the min heap
}

int main() {
        priority_queue<Node*,vector<Node*>,comparitor<Node*>> pq;// min heap please, comparitor is just for node and not a template, though I could have easily created that.
}
```

Comment: You should remove all the code which is not absolutely necessary and create a MCVE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3):

`std::priority_queue`, expects three arguments -- all are types. What you are passing is a function. Change `comparitor` to a class with an `operator()` function.

```
// There is no reason to make it a class template. This is specifically
// designed to work only with Node*
struct comparitor
{
    bool operator()(const Node* a, const Node* b) const
    {
       return (a->freq > b->freq);
    }
};
```

and use it as:

```
priority_queue<Node*, vector<Node*>, comparitor> pq;
```

Comment: Yes, This worked. One thing though, the bool operator should be public. class Compare
{
    public:
  bool operator()( Node*a,  Node*b) 
  {
    return a->freq>b->freq;
  }
};

Comment: @AshishGupta, `comparitor` is a `struct`, not a `class`. The function is `public`.

Comment: Thanks a ton, @R Sahu.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler error pretty much gives you the answer, the third template parameter should be a type but you are passing a function pointer.

You need to convert `comparitor` into a functor:

```
template<typename T>
struct comparitor
{
  bool operator()(T a, T b)
  {
    if(a->freq>b->freq)
    {return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    } // this is for the min heap
  }
};
```

Comment: @user4581301 only with c++20's default constructible lambdas: http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2017/p0624r0.pdf

Comment: I didn't know about that. What I had in mind requires a stop-over in a `std::function` to work here.